# Writing custom directive to add tooltips to ng-options in AngularJS (TypeScript)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive, ng-options

I have some HTML that is currently populating a select box using the `ng-options` directive. Our problem is that ng-options doesn't support using tooltips. To solve this, I am trying to write a custom directive  but I am pretty new to AngularJS and TypeScript, so I'm not sure where to go from where I am.

Here is the relevant code so far:

### HTML

```html
<select grid-column-tooltip class="select-box" id="availableColumn" size="5" 
        ng-options="column as column.localizedTitle for column in vm.availableColumns | filter: vm.environmentMatches track by column.field" 
        ng-model="vm.availableColumnElement"
        ng-dblclick="vm.moveToSelectedColumns()">
    <option value="" ng-if="false"></option>
</select>
```

There is a field on the `column` object called `environmentLabel` that I want to display as a tooltip upon hovering.

### Javascript

```js
module psfc {
class GirdColumnTooltipDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    restrict = 'A';

    template = '<div class="grid-column-tooltip">{{column.environmentLabel}}</div>';
    constructor(
    ) { }       

    static directive = (): ng.IDirectiveFactory => {
        return () => new GirdColumnTooltipDirective();
    }
}

angular
    .module('psfc')
    .directive('gridColumnTooltip', GirdColumnTooltipDirective.directive());
}
```

This is obviously very incomplete because I am unsure how to implement what I want in typescript. I am also unsure whether or not to make the template into a `div` that appears upon hovering, or finding a way to add the `title` attribute to the relevant `option` element.

Also, depending on what the solution is, I'm not worried about the CSS for now. I can fix any style problems later.

Comment: Why are you taging with TypeScript ? If it is AngularJS it is Javascript, not TypeScript. You might get better help with the right tags.

Comment: It's both. AngularJS can be TypeScript or pure Javascript. In this case, I'd like to use AngularJS for TypeScript.

Comment: Since you are new to AngularJS, consider using the custom select plugins, because working with ng-options will either be too difficult or the result will be full of bugs. And this question is all about AngularJS, not TypeScript, so please remove the `typescript` tag.

Comment: have you considered using $uibpopover from bootstraps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity's sake, we ended up just changing the `ng-options` to use `ng-repeat` inside the `select`. Much simpler than writing a custom directive.

### HTML

```html
<select class="select-box" id="availableColumn" size="5"
        ng-dblclick="vm.moveToSelectedColumns()">
    <option ng-repeat="column in vm.availableColumns | filter: vm.environmentMatches track by column.field"
            value="column.field"
            ng-click="vm.availableColumnElement = column"
            title="{{column.localizedTitle}}">
         {{column.localizedTitle}}
     </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Note that the `option` tag does not allow the `title` attribute. Even if it works in some browsers, it is not according to the standard and not all browsers support it. For example, Edge does not show the title.

Comment: I understand that it isn't the standard since `option` is an incomplete part of the `select` element, but after testing, it seems to work in all browsers that we support (including Edge and IE).